# The Road to a Fulfilling Life

Tags: mathematics, word, knowledge, word-property, geography

The final answer is a 12-letter word and is confirmed by the title.
<sub>Other applicable tags: visual, enigmatic puzzle, rebus (stage 2)</sub>

**Stage 1 of 2:**
Mark the correct cells black in the 5 grids below and put the results together to move to Stage 2 of 2. The grids are completely independent and can be worked on independently, in any order.  Grid #2 is probably the easiest, followed by #5 and #4. Grids #1 and #3 are probably the toughest.

---

**Grid #1:**
Start on the black square marked "start" and move through the grid according to the clue, marking the cells on the path black.
**Theme:** Word property
**Clue:** Adjacent (including diagonally) r _ _ _ _ _ i c
[image: Grid#1]

Text version of Grid #1:
A 7-row, 5-column grid with the following values:

```
 42, 28, 73,106, 54  
 67,105,150,116,109  
 17, 78, 10,146,160  
 41, 74, 92, 65,111  
 70, 39, 30, 59,115  
 44, 90,  8,  5, 11  
 51, 13, 62,  6, 80
```

---

**Grid #2:**
Start on the black square marked "start", but no need to path through the grid as in grid #1. Instead, based on the start cell, mark all cells matching the clue black.
**Theme:** Mathematics
**Clue:** f a c _ _ _ _
[image: Grid#2]

Text version of Grid #2:
A 7-row, 5-column grid with the following values:

```
  11, 56, 19, 44, 14  
 144, 22, 13, 64, 76  
   9, 12, 30,  8,121  
  60, 32, 36, 80, 40  
   6,100, 48,  7, 20  
  10, 82, 16, 90, 15  
  17,  5, 24,120, 18
```

---

**Grid #3:**
Mark all cells matching the clue black.
**Theme:** Word property
**Clue:** l i p _ _ _ _ _ with an "I" <sub>(the character in quotation marks is an uppercase I, not a lowercase l)</sub>
[image: Grid#3]

Text version of Grid #3:
A 7-row, 5-column grid with the following values:

```
   6,  4, 10,103, 50  
  74,153, 63, 16, 12  
 122, 84,156, 69,131  
 184, 23,172,140,105  
  29, 65,116, 83, 24  
 120, 95, 48, 52,  2  
  46, 41,102,  7,191
```

---

**Grid #4:**
Mark all cells matching the clue black.
**Theme:** USA geography
**Clue:** _ a n d _ _ _ _ _ d
[image: Grid#4]

Text version of Grid #4:
A 7-row, 5-column grid with the following values:

```
 WA,NM,MN,OK,OR  
 AR,AK,TX,MT,PA
 CO,VA,AZ,HI,VT
 KS,SC,MI,FL,UT
 KY,CA,ID,NC,WY
 WV,NE,AL,ME,OH
 NY,ND,TN,NV,GA
```

---

**Grid #5:**
Mark all cells matching the clue black.
**Theme:** Word property
**Clue:** P _ _ i _ _ _ _ _ e
[image: Grid#5]

Text version of Grid #5:
A 7-row, 5-column grid with the following values:

```
 BEG,OAR,KEY,DOT,ICE  
 HUB,PUN,AGE,GOT,CRY  
 EVE,NUN,DID,PEP,EYE  
 SAT,NIP,FUN,AHA,URN  
 LEG,RUG,YAY,TOY,MET  
 WHY,WOW,EAR,JOG,VEX 
 POP,BIB,SIS,MOM,DAD
```

---

**Stage 2:**
(Easy)
This stage will provide the final answer, which is a 12-letter word.

Comment: 2-5 are pretty easy, but I'm having trouble seeing what 1 is cluing...

Comment: I feel like I have something that seems feasible for 1, but it's not entirely working out.

Comment: @Deusovi I leaned to the easy side on this one, since my last multi-stage puzzle took 2 weeks to be solved completely. :) Were you able to get the word for grid #1 and still it doesn't give you anything?

Comment: Never mind, just figured out 1.

Comment: @JLee There are a few possible words that fit that pattern, none of which give me any particularly relevant ideas. I could just be missing the obvious, though...

Comment: (But it looks like it's gettable!)

Comment: @Deusovi The word clues for both 1 and 3 were new to me, so I consider those the most difficult ones.

Comment: Ahh, just found the word!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Grid 1's hint is "rhopalic". A rhopalic sentence is one where each word is one letter longer than the previous. Starting at "six", a three-letter word, you can trace a path going up to "one hundred fifteen", with 17 letters; this draws out a `Q`.
>
>  [image: grid 1]
>
>  Grid 2's hint is "factors" [of 120, the starting number]. Shading all the factors of 120 draws out a lowercase `o`.
>  [image: grid 2]
>
>  Grid 3's hint is "lipogram (with an `I`)". A lipogram is a piece of text that is intentionally missing a specific letter. Shading all the numbers that aren't spelled with an `I` draws out the letter `S`.
>  [image: grid 3]
>
>  Grid 4's hint is "landlocked". Shading all the landlocked US states draws out the number 0.
>  [image: grid 4]
>
>  Grid 5's hint is "palindrome". Shading all the palindromes gives the letter `z`.
>  [image: grid 5]

We now have

> the code `QoS0z`. Going to `i.stack.imgur.com/QoS0z.png` gives the second part of the puzzle:
>
>  [image: step 2]
>
>
>  The six subtractions are:
>  PINCERS - PIERS → **NC**
>  CRATE - RAT = **CE**
>  SHRIMP - SHIM = **RP**
>  VENT - ET = **VN**
>  GROVES - ROES = **GV**
>  BREAD - RED = **BA**
>
>  This creates the 12-letter string `NCCERPVNGVBA`; this rot13s to the answer, **APPRECIATION**.

Comment: not that it matters, but the 30 on Grid #1 is shaded also. great job. very fast.

Answer (score 3):

### Grid #1:

> Clue: Adjacent (including diagonally) rhopalic
>  Rule: Shade each cell on the path where each number, written out, has one more letter than the previous one.
>  Extracted character: **Q**
>  [image: Grid #1 Image]

### Grid #2:

> Clue: Factors
>  Rule: Shade each cell which is a factor of 120.
>  Extracted character: **o**
>  [image: Grid #2 Image]

### Grid #3:

> Clue: Lipogram with an "I"
>  Rule: Shade each cell with a number which, written out, does not contain the letter "I".
>  Extracted character: **9**
>  [image: Grid #3 Image]

### Grid #4:

> Clue: Landlocked
>  Rule: Shade each cell with the abbreviation for a landlocked US state.
>  Extracted character: **0**
>  [image: Grid #4 Image]

### Grid #5:

> Clue: Palindrome
>  Rule: Shade each cell whose three letter word is a palindrome.
>  Extracted character: **z**
>  [image: Grid #5 Image]

### Stage 2 [UNSOLVED]:

> The extracted letters spell out: **Qo90z**. These characters look fairly random, and look like some string that would be appended to a link, e.g. Imgur. This idea is strengthened by the specification of capital vs. lowercase letters in the grids. I haven't found anything with that, though. There's also the "rebus" tag associated with Stage 2 of the puzzle, so this string of 5 letters may in a rebus sense resolve to a 12 letter answer.

Comment: Great job. +1 Deusovi is a tough competitor. He's been doing these a while!

Comment: Probably should've realized that rot13(gur fgnpx+vzthe yvaxf rkvfg, tvira gung gurl nccrne svir gvzrf va zl jevgrhc, unun)